# query not selected closest values

Tags: mysql, pdo

I think this line: `Poscode , ABS( Poscode - :distance ) AS distance` in below code,is being ignored:

SO it's just taking this line into consideration thus return the exact records for the postcode provided, instead of listing all closest records to the postcode given!

```
$bindings[] = array(":distance", $postcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Query:

```
$rate=$data['slider1'];

$key =array_keys($data['sub']); 
//print_r($key);
$pricing2 = $data['slider1'];
$pricing = $pricing2 * 1.15;
$postcode = $data['postcode'];


$bindings = array();
$bindings[] = array(":pricing", $pricing, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$bindings[] = array(":distance", $postcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$key_placeholders = array();
foreach($key as $k => $v) {
    $placeholder = ":subid".$k;
    $bindings[] = array($placeholder, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $key_placeholders[] = $placeholder;
}
$sql = "SELECT Name,PostUUID,pricing,Poscode , ABS( Poscode - :distance ) AS distance,subname,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,week_morning,week_afternoon,week_evening,weekend_morning,week_afternoon,week_evening,weekend_morning,weekend_afternoon,week_evening,weekend_morning,weekend_afternoon,weekend_evening,date,Phone,Sex,UUID,catname FROM posts,subjects,categories "
        . "WHERE posts.subid IN (". implode(",",$key_placeholders).") "
        . "AND posts.pricing <=:pricing "
        . "AND posts.Poscode =:distance "
        . "AND posts.subid=subjects.subid "
        . "AND subjects.catid=categories.catid "
        . "ORDER BY distance "
        . "DESC LIMIT 100";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($bindings as $b) {
    $statement->bindValue($b[0],$b[1],$b[2]);
}
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: wont ABS( Poscode - :distance ) always = 0 due to the posts.Poscode =:distance in the WHERE clause

Comment: @PaulF, I was suspecting it, but do I use <=:distance or >= distance instead?

Comment: Not sure if is as simple as just removing that part of the WHERE clause, after all you are ordering by distance & selecting the top 100, so the first result will be nearest - so matching postcode if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` part of the statement chooses what data to return for each row - so `ABS( Poscode - :distance ) AS distance` will return a field called `distance` that is the difference between the field `Poscode` and the value `:distance` for each row.

The `WHERE` part of the statement chooses which rows to return.

Therefore if you want to change what rows are returned (to get entries within a given distance) you need to change your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I think this line is wrong: . "AND posts.Poscode =:distance " in the WHERE clause...Could you tell me how do I change it please to get nearest values..

Comment: @Vani Yes, that line will limit your results to just those where `Poscode` is equal to your distance variable. 1) What are you counting as 'near'? 2) What does your `Poscode` field contain? It sounds like it should be a postcode (e.g. `AB12 3DEF`), but you're comparing it with a distance (e.g. `10`).